# How can I draw a scatter plot using Scala-Chart?

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a minimal working example (MWE) of a scatter plot using the [Scala-Chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart) library for Scala. The documentation talks only about line charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to first create an XYLineChart and then reset its renderer to a new renderer that will draw shapes instead of lines:

```
object MyChartApp extends App with scalax.chart.module.Charting {
  val data = for (i <- 1 to 5) yield (i,i)
  val chart = XYLineChart(data)
  chart.plot.setRenderer(new org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer(false, true))
  chart.saveAsPNG("/tmp/chart.png")
}
```

I have created a pull request (https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart/pull/27) with a new chart factory that will allow scatter plots to be created as follows:

```
object MyChartApp extends App with scalax.chart.module.Charting {
  val data = for (i <- 1 to 5) yield (i,i)
  val chart = XYScatterChart(data)
  chart.saveAsPNG("/tmp/chart.png")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your pull request (as it is sadly not accepted yet), it can be done this way (in an inelegant way):

```
object MyChartApp extends App with scalax.chart.module.Charting {
  val data = for (i <- 1 to 5) yield (i,i)
  val plot = XYLineChart(data).plot
  plot.setRenderer(new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(false, true))
  val chartScatter = XYChart(plot, title = "", legend = true)(theme = ChartTheme.Default)
  chart.saveAsPNG("/tmp/chart.png")
}
```